# Is there any way to unpack an iterator into a tuple?

Tags: rust

Is there any way to accomplish something like the following:

```
let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
let (a, b) = v.iter().take(2);
```

Such that `a = 1` and `b = 2` at the end?

I know I could just use a vector but I would like to have named variables.

Comment: One issue is that tuple is type.  So tuple with 2 elements is distinct type from tuple of 3 elements. take(2) might not be best function here, but you would probably require special macro that returns appropriate type based on number you pass in.

Comment: What behavior do you want when the vector contains less than two items?

Comment: @Shepmaster that is an excellent question. In that light I can't think of a good enough reason for this functionality to be possible.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This may not be exactly what you asked for, but I suppose you rarely want to convert an arbitrarily large vector to a tuple anyway. If you just want to extract the first few elements of a vector into a tuple, you can do so using *slice pattern matching*:

```
fn main() {
    let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let (a, b) = match &v[..] {
        &[first, second, ..] => (first, second),
        _ => unreachable!(),
    };
    assert_eq!((a, b), (1, 2));
}
```

Comment: I like this, but it would be nice to have something more concise. Making a function that returns `(v[0].clone(), v[1].clone())` seems to work as well. Is there an advantage one way or the other?

Comment: Apart from the cloning, one obvious disadvantage would be that `v[i]` might panic unless you explicitly check for the Vec's length, which would make the code less concise. Using pattern matching, the compiler checks if the match is exhaustive and requires you to handle Vec's of any arbitrary length. Of course, you shouldn't just use the unreachable! macro like above unless the Vec's length is known in advance.

Comment: As of `rustc 1.12.0`, slice pattern syntax is still experimental. See [Issue #23121](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/23121)

Answer (score 32):

The itertools crate has methods like [`tuples`](https://docs.rs/itertools/*/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.tuples) and [`next_tuple`](https://docs.rs/itertools/*/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.next_tuple) that can help with this.

```
use itertools::Itertools; // 0.9.0

fn main() {
    let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let (a, b) = v.iter().next_tuple().unwrap();

    assert_eq!(a, &1);
    assert_eq!(b, &2);
}
```

Comment: [collect_tuple](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.10.0/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.collect_tuple) is also relevant

Answer (score 6):

I wrote this ugly recursive macro that converts a `Vec` to a tuple because I wanted to learn something about macros.

```
macro_rules! tuplet {
    { ($y:ident $(, $x:ident)*) = $v:expr } => {
        let ($y, $($x),*) = tuplet!($v ; 1 ; ($($x),*) ; ($v[0]) );
    };
    { $v:expr ; $j:expr ; ($y:ident $(, $x:ident)*) ; ($($a:expr),*) } => {
        tuplet!( $v ; $j+1 ; ($($x),*) ; ($($a),*,$v[$j]) )
    };
    { $v:expr ; $j:expr ; () ; $accu:expr } => {
        $accu
    }
}
```

I am new to this and probably very bad at it, so there's most likely a better way to do it. This is just a proof of concept. It allows you to write:

```
fn main() {
    let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
    tuplet!((a, b, c) = v);

    assert_eq!(a, 1);
    assert_eq!(b, 2);
    assert_eq!(c, 3);
}
```

Somewhere in that macro definition you find the part `$v[$j]`, which you could replace by `$v.nth($j)` if you want to use it for iterators.

Answer (score 2):

gcp is on the right track; his answer seems like the correct one to me.

I'm going to give a more compelling example, though, since the OP seemed in a comment to wonder whether what he asked for is even worthwhile ("I can't think of a good enough reason for this functionality to be possible.").  Check out the `Person::from_csv` function below:

```
use itertools::Itertools;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Person<'a> {
    first: &'a str,
    last:  &'a str,
}

impl<'a> Person<'a> {
    // Create a Person from a str of form "last,first".
    fn from_csv(s: &'a str) -> Option<Self> {
        s.split(',').collect_tuple().map(
            |(last, first)| Person { first, last }
        )
    }
}

fn main() {
    dbg!(Person::from_csv("Doe"));          // None
    dbg!(Person::from_csv("Doe,John"));     // Some(...)
    dbg!(Person::from_csv("Doe,John,foo")); // None
}
```

It takes the Iterator produced by `split` and collects the results into a tuple so that we can match and destructure it.  If there are too many or too few commas, you won't get a matching tuple.  This code is clean because `collect_tuple` lets us use pattern matching and destructuring.

Here it is [in the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1638b1a9368b193f58f70e97ffcb2ca9).