# Is there a way to cut up a string by whitespace?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to automatically split up a string by line, and then by whitespace for use in a Vec of Vec3.

```
v 0.500000 0.500000 -0.500000
v 0.500000 -0.500000 -0.500000
v 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000
v 0.500000 -0.500000 0.500000
v -0.500000 0.500000 -0.500000
v -0.500000 -0.500000 -0.500000
v -0.500000 0.500000 0.500000
v -0.500000 -0.500000 0.500000
vt 0.875000 0.500000
vt 0.625000 0.750000
vt 0.625000 0.500000
```

For example, given this sample, I would want to discard lines starting with "vt", and store the coordinates from the lines starting with "v".

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.split

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `str::split_whitespace()`. Here's a simple parser. It does not handle errors (instead panics), but it should be a good starting point:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Vec3(f32, f32, f32);

fn main() {
    let str = "v 0.500000 0.500000 -0.500000
v 0.500000 -0.500000 -0.500000
v 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000
v 0.500000 -0.500000 0.500000
v -0.500000 0.500000 -0.500000
v -0.500000 -0.500000 -0.500000
v -0.500000 0.500000 0.500000
v -0.500000 -0.500000 0.500000
vt 0.875000 0.500000
vt 0.625000 0.750000
vt 0.625000 0.500000";

    let parsed = str
        .split("\n")
        .filter_map(|line| {
            let mut parts = line.split_whitespace();
            if parts.next().unwrap() == "v" {
                Some(Vec3(
                    parts.next().unwrap().parse().unwrap(),
                    parts.next().unwrap().parse().unwrap(),
                    parts.next().unwrap().parse().unwrap(),
                ))
            } else {
                None
            }
        })
        .collect::<Vec<Vec3>>();

    dbg!(parsed);
}
```

Output:

```
[src/main.rs:33] parsed = [
    Vec3(
        0.5,
        0.5,
        -0.5,
    ),
    Vec3(
        0.5,
        -0.5,
        -0.5,
    ),
    Vec3(
        0.5,
        0.5,
        0.5,
    ),
    Vec3(
        0.5,
        -0.5,
        0.5,
    ),
    Vec3(
        -0.5,
        0.5,
        -0.5,
    ),
    Vec3(
        -0.5,
        -0.5,
        -0.5,
    ),
    Vec3(
        -0.5,
        0.5,
        0.5,
    ),
    Vec3(
        -0.5,
        -0.5,
        0.5,
    ),
]
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7e2900eeb6e4b13de87496aaa8dfb4e1)

Answer (score 0):

Between the use of [`lines`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.lines) and [`split_whitespace`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.split_whitespace), you can step through both of your iterators to do something like this to collect each row into its own vec3:

```rust
const data: &'static str = r"v 0.500000 0.500000 -0.500000
v 0.500000 -0.500000 -0.500000
v 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000
v 0.500000 -0.500000 0.500000
v -0.500000 0.500000 -0.500000
v -0.500000 -0.500000 -0.500000
v -0.500000 0.500000 0.500000
v -0.500000 -0.500000 0.500000
vt 0.875000 0.500000
vt 0.625000 0.750000
vt 0.625000 0.500000";

fn main() {
    for row in data.lines() {
        let mut cols = row.split_whitespace();

        if Some("vt") != cols.next() {
            let vec3 = (
                cols.next().unwrap().parse::<f32>().unwrap(),
                cols.next().unwrap().parse::<f32>().unwrap(),
                cols.next().unwrap().parse::<f32>().unwrap(),
            );
            println!("{:?}", vec3);
        }
    }
}
```

You can simplify that a bit by using a crate to unpack the iterator into a tuple without needing to touch each element: [Is there any way to unpack an iterator into a tuple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29504873/is-there-any-way-to-unpack-an-iterator-into-a-tuple)