# Rust collect() tuple with more than two elements

Tags: rust, iterator, tuples

I'm having a hard time collecting the tuple with these three elements:

```
let create_task = |msg| {
    // We need to keep the message_id to report failures to SQS
    // and the receipt_handle to delete the processed messages from SQS.
    let SqsMessageObj {
        message_id,
        body,
        receipt_handle,
        ..
    } = msg;

    let span = tracing::span!(tracing::Level::INFO, "Handling SQS msg", message_id);
    let task = async {
        let item = serde_json::from_value(body)?;
        f(item, app_config).await
    };

    (
        message_id.unwrap_or_default(),
        receipt_handle.unwrap_or_default(),
        task,
    )
};

print!("{:?}", event.payload);

let (ids, receipts, tasks) = event.payload.records.into_iter().map(create_task).collect();
```

This is based on the AWS-labs example code of advanced SQS batch processing with Rust lambda.

I have tried the solution from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29504873/is-there-any-way-to-unpack-an-iterator-into-a-tuple), and it seems like I got a nested tuple instead. Any clue?

Comment: What is `event.payload`?

Comment: It's an SQS event payload.

Comment: What is its type?

Comment: It's a `pub struct LambdaEvent<T>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`unzip()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.unzip) with a nested tuple:

```rust
let create_task = |msg| {
    // We need to keep the message_id to report failures to SQS
    let SqsMessageObj {
        message_id,
        body,
        message_attributes,
        receipt_handle,
        ..
    } = msg;

    let span = tracing::span!(tracing::Level::INFO, "Handling SQS msg", message_id);
    let task = async {
        let item = serde_json::from_value(body)?;
        f(item, app_config).await
    };

    (
        (
            message_id.unwrap_or_default(),
            receipt_handle.unwrap_or_default(),
        ),
        task,
    )
};

print!("{:?}", event.payload);

let ((ids, receipts), tasks) = event.payload.records.into_iter().map(create_task).unzip();
```

Comment: No, I can't. That was the original code. It expect tuple with two elements.

Comment: `mismatched types
expected tuple `(_, _)`
   found tuple `(_, _, _)``

Comment: @Seto In your code there was tuple with three elements.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I missunderstood

Comment: Ok, now I need to anotate the tuple. I think that was the original problem.

Comment: What is the type of task? I can't just put `Future`there.

Comment: `let ((ids, receipts), tasks): ((_, _), _) =
        event.payload.records.into_iter().map(create_task).unzip();`